# gear icon at the bottom right of the Android SDK Manager window when I click there is no options of repositories

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

gear icon at the bottom right of the Android SDK Manager window when I click there is no options of repositories .so I am not able to change to google repository from Microsoft repository , has anyone else faced this problem please help

Comment: Welocome to SO! The gear icon contains the function before `16.6.2` of Visusla Stuido 2019. I'm not sure which version begins to dismiss this option at least from `16.7.0`. You can suggest a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html). There will be Microsoft engineers to check that. If there are any news,engineers will mark you there.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which invalidates one or more answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. Thus, I have reverted your edit. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `Gear Icon` works only with VS-2017 Not with VS-2019.

And in VS-2019 the SDK used is kind of combined one, soo if you want to add any google SDK, add it directly by the Android SDK Manager from Visual Studio.

Another way is to set the SDK path of Android Studio & Visual Studio(*Tool - Options - Xamarin - Android SDK, check path) to the same. Goto Android Studio & download the SDK you want, it will reflect in Visual Studio as well.

> Visual Studio 19

[image: Visual Studio 19]

> Visual Studio 17

[image: Visual Studio 17]

> Visual Studio 17 when set to MicrosoftSDK

[image: VS17 error]

You must use the Google one, not Microsoft SDK

---

go to `Tools` - `Options..` - Dialog box appears - `Select Xamarin` - `Android Settings` - Check the SDK path

Copy that path & paste the path in the URL section of `My Computer`

Comment: Hii Blu actually the error I am getting is android instance not found check internet connectionand fix for the problem given everywhere is change repository using gear icon to google but as you said in gear option we can't change it so how to do that ?

Comment: check updated answer, I have attached screenshots for a better understanding. And can you add you error screenshot in question like what it means, I'm not getting it good - internet issue.

Comment: Check the edit at the end of the answer, if your question changes, post it with a new question, don't update it with the previous one. If it works fine, you can mark it as correc & give a upvote